# How to show a SnackBar when the Form opens in Flutter

Tags: flutter, snackbar

I would like to show a SnackBar when a form opens with instructions as to how to interact with the form. I tried to use FlushBar, and it kind of worked, because the SnackBar appeared but not dismissed itself after the duration I set, and it interfered with the GestureDetector on a ListView on that form, which did not accept taps  anymore.Then I tried the default SnackBar, which did not give me any errors but did not appear either.
I tried both approaches in the "Widget build" function and in the initState function.
If anyone has a working example with any of those widgets I'd be very grateful. Nothing fancy just two lines of text.I found an example of something similar to my question in another question here, but it was not Flutter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading through this SnackBar tutorial - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars

In the tutorial, they access the Scaffold using `Scaffold.of(context)`. However, that can also be achieved by creating and assigning a scaffoldKey to Scaffold(), this way is:

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
Scaffold(key: scaffoldKey)
```

And when you wish to open the SnackBar, use this `scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar()`